# Dart, Why Iterable<T> can store in List<T> variable?

Tags: dart

Why Dart allow me to store `Iterable<T>` in `List<T>` variable?

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3].map((i) => i);
```

It's caused a lot of problems when I use `map` function because it returns me `Iterable<T>` then I store to `list` variable.

When I try to get an element from `list` using `list[0]` it will cause an error.

Comment: Conceptually, an `Iterable<T>` is a generalisation of all "collections of things" - consider a Linked-List vs. an Array - they're both iterable but only the Array supports direct indexing (at least in `O(1)` time). Additionally (especially in other languages like JavaScript, Python and C# - and I think Dart too), an Iterable can also represent a "generator function" that emits dynamically-generated values, not just an in-memory collection.

Comment: @Dai I knew that but question is Why is allow be to set Iterable to List variable. That's wired because why other consumer of list need to care that it's able to use [] or not?

Comment: When I put your code into DartPad I get a compile error saying that "Instance of '`MappedListIterable<int, int>`': type '`MappedListIterable<int, int>`' is not a subtype of type '`List<int>`'`.

Comment: What version of Dart are you using? Can you reproduce this using DartPad or any other online Dart compiler?

Comment: @Dai I reproduced this in DartPad it's reproduced. Your error is not an compile time error. The exception will be raised when you use list[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart currently allows *implicit downcasts*.

When you try to store a value with static type *S* in a variable of a type *T*, then:
* If *T* is a supertype of *S*, then it just works.
* If *S* is a subtype of *T*, then the compiler inserts an implicit downcast to the subtype
* Otherwise it's a compile-time error.

This means that:

```dart
List<int> iterable = [1, 2, 3].map((e) => e);
```

is compiled as

```dart
List<int> iterable = [1, 2, 3].map((e) => e) as List<int>;
```

That will *fail at runtime* when it tries to do that cast. And it does fail.

It should not fail when you try to read an element, it should fail immediately when you try to assign the iterable to the list variable. If it doesn't, it's probably because you are compiling to JavaScript. The JavaScript compiler *omits* a number of run-time type checks under the assumption that they'll probably succeed (that's an unsafe optimization, but nevertheless an optimization with a significant impact). So, you are doing an unsafe downcast, the language inserts a check to make sure it's safe, then the compiler omits that check again, and you get the bad behavior later than intended.

Exactly the iterable/list subtyping has caused a lot of issues because it's so easy to accidentally create an iterable when you meant it to be a list.
When Dart introduces non-nullable types, it would get even worse, so at that point, it will remove the implicit downcast feature, and you will get an error when trying to assign an iterable to a list variable.

Comment: Hi @Irn, Could you explains more, Why introduces non-null types make this even worse? :)

Comment: A reasons for non-nullable types is to avoid passing `null` where it's not expected. That'll be a statically detected error. There will be two variants of a type, like `int` and `int?`, where only the latter allows `null`. If you expect an `int`, and someone gives you a `null`, the compiler stops them. And if you have a nullable variable, `int? maybeNull;` and assigns it to a non-nullable variable `int notNull = maybeNull;` the compiler *should* stop you. But `int` is a subtype of `int?`, so if you still have *implicit downcasts*, that assignment would be allowed. So Null Safety removes those.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `.toList()` method on the `Iterable`.

```dart
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3].map((i) => i).toList();
```

Comment: This still not an answer. I know I needed to do toList. But it's allow me not to do. What if I forget to do toList. Why other consumer of this variable should care about if I able to use [] or not?

Answer (score -1):

Your code throws a runtime error, even before using the `[]` operator, because the [.map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) function returns an `Iterable<T>` (that doesn't have the `[]` operator) which cannot be cast to a `List<T>`. You either want to use [.toList](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) to convert your `Iterable<T>` to a `List<T>` or [.elementAt(index)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) can be used instead of `[]`.

For example:

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3].map((e) => e).toList(); // Using .toMap
list[1]; // Get the second value.

var iterable = [1, 2, 3].map((e) => e); //Using elementAt
iterable.elementAt(1); // Get the second value.
```

Comment: Try it... It's allow me to do that's why I'm asking this question. Actually it shouldn't be runtime error but compile time error.